# Calculate Document Height With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've developed a site utilizing JQuery and have applied all styles on the pages using JQuery commands in such a way that I can calculate property values using numbers pulled from javascript functions like window.innerHeight. It works great. But now I'm attempting to calculate the height of the document (not the Window Height, mind you), subtract the height of the footer, and position a "shadow" image just above the footer. I'm having trouble with this, though, as Safari seems to miscalculate that number and position the shadow element haphazardly, seemingly coming up with a slightly different position every time.

```
$("div#shadowBottom").css({
"position":"absolute",
"top":(window.scrollMaxY-$(".footer").css("height").replace("px","")-50)+"px",
"left":"0px",
"width":"100%"
"height":"50px"
});
```

I've also tried wrapping the document in a div and calculating the height of that minus the height of the .footer element and height of the #shadowBottom element to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
var body = document.body;
var html = document.documentElement;
var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked perfectly:

```
$("div#gradientBottom").css({
    "background":"url(\"gradientBottom.png\")",
    "position":"absolute",
    "top":(Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight)-$(".footer").css("height").replace("px","")-50)+"px",
    "left":"0px",
    "width":"100%",
    "height":"50px"
});
```